# Target invokation exception while copying file?

Tags: c#, .net, file, file-io

I am getting TargetInvokationException while using the following function

```
    File.Copy(Source, Destination) ;
```

Source contains the full address of the file to be copied
Destination contains the address of the directory where the file is to be copied. 
When I comment out the above line no exception occurs .
Why is this exception occurring?

Sample input

```
    Source = "C:\\Users\Pratik\\abcd.mp3" ;   
    Destination = "C:\\Users\\Pratik\\Desktop" ;
```

I tried to catch the exception bu using

```
   try
   { 
     File.Open(Source, Destination) ; 
   }
   catch(System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException)
   {
       // Display the error
    }
```

but, 
When I run the program Visual Studio debugger takes me to the line

```
    Application.Run(new FormClass()) ;
```

instead of catching the exception.

Comment: That code won't throw a `TargetInvocationException`. The exception itself will contain enough details, but I guess you're calling this code from an application that has no permissions to write in `Destination`.

Comment: did you search with exception names , it is from CLR , it must have explanation in MSDN

Comment: @ImranRizvi searched for it but I can't understand why the exception is occurring while copying the file?

Comment: What is File object, .Net or any custom class?

Comment: @ImranRizvi It's a .Net class

Comment: Is the error occurs if you run your program with Administrative privileges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your destination is a folder, it needs to also include the file name.

- File.Copy(string sourceFileName, string destFileName)
- You only have a single backslash in part of your source path.

Handy tip, use the @ (at) symbol to avoid needing to escape slashes.

```
var source      = @"C:\Users\Pratik\abcd.mp3";
var destination = @"C:\Users\Pratik\Desktop\abdc.mp3";
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, the error was so obvious, yet I couldn't spot it!. I lost 1 hr on this whole error!. Sometimes, you need a different set of eyes to debug.

Comment: But can you tell, why there is "TargetInvocationException".

Comment: I do not know, but if you get an error like that again, look for an 'InnerException' message within the exception object, as it often gives more details.